# Does anyone see the mistake/problem with my code (MCMC using emcee)?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, data-fitting, model-fitting, emcee

Does anyone see the problem with my code? I am trying to set up a rather easy example of fitting some mock data to a lognormal function using emcee but MCMC does not produce a feasible fit like curve-fit. I am writing this post because after looking through several examples on the internet, I still cannot see a mistake in my code and think that there might be another issue. Thank you in advance for helping me out.

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import emcee
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import corner

def lognormal(x, A, mu, sigma):
     return A * 1/(x * sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu)**2/(2 * sigma**2))

#MCMC

def mcmc(x_data, y_data, func, initial_guess = [1,1,1], burning_in = 200, thinner = 50, steps = 5000, walkers = 100, dimension = 3):
#Scipy curve fit

    curve_fit_params, cov= curve_fit(func, x_data, y_data, p0 = initial_guess)

    curve_fit_error = np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))


    #MCMCM setup

    # Define the log-likelihood function

    def log_likelihood(theta, x, y, func):
        A, mu, sigma = theta
        y_model = func(x, A, mu, sigma)
        residual = y - y_model
        chi_squared = np.sum(residual**2)
        log_like = -0.5 * chi_squared
        return log_like


    # Define the log-prior function
    def log_prior(theta):
        A, mu, sigma = theta
        # Add any prior constraints here
        # For example, uniform priors for A, mu and sigma between certain ranges
        if 0 < A < 2.*curve_fit_params[0] and 0 < mu < 2.*curve_fit_params[1] and 0 < sigma < 2.*curve_fit_params[2]:
            return 0.0  # log(1) = 0
        return -np.inf  # log(0) = -inf

    # Define the log-posterior function
    def log_posterior(theta, x, y, func):
        log_prior_val = log_prior(theta)
        if not np.isfinite(log_prior_val):
            return -np.inf  # log(0) = -inf
        log_like_val = log_likelihood(theta, x, y, func)
        return log_prior_val + log_like_val

    #MCMC

    # Set up the number of walkers and dimensions
    nwalkers = walkers
    ndim = dimension

    # Initialize the walkers with random positions near the maximum likelihood solution
    pos = [0.1 * np.random.randn(ndim) + curve_fit_params for _ in range(nwalkers)]

    # Set up the emcee sampler
    sampler = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, ndim, log_posterior, args=(x_data, y_data, func))

    # Run the MCMC sampling
    nsteps = steps  # Number of steps to run the sampler
    sampler.run_mcmc(pos, nsteps, progress = True)

    #tau = sampler.get_autocorr_time()
    #print(tau)

    # Get the chain of samples and flatten it
    samples = sampler.get_chain(discard=burning_in, thin = thinner, flat=True)

    # Get the best-fit parameters (maximum a posteriori or MAP estimate)
    mcmc_fit_mean = np.mean(samples, axis=0)

    # Get the uncertainties in the parameters (credible intervals)
    mcmc_fit_std = np.std(samples, axis=0)

    #corner plot

    labels = ["A", "mu", "sigma"]

    fig = corner.corner(samples, bins = 100, plot_datapoints=False, smooth = True, labels=labels, truths=curve_fit_params, truth_color = 'darkred', color = '#002448', quantiles=[0.16, 0.50, 0.84], hist_kwargs={"density": True, "alpha": 0.4, "histtype": "stepfilled"})
    #plt.savefig('MCMC_test_convergence.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=800)
    plt.show()
    plt.clf()
    
    return samples, mcmc_fit_mean, mcmc_fit_std, curve_fit_params, curve_fit_error



#test data

n_sample = 1000

x_test = np.linspace(0.001,250, n_sample)

y_test = lognormal(x_test, 0.8, 4.7, 0.4) + np.random.normal(0, 0.0003, n_sample)


plt.scatter(x_test, y_test, linewidth  = 0.5, s = 1, color = 'darkred')
plt.show()
plt.clf()



result = mcmc(x_test, y_test, lognormal)
print('MCMC results: ', *result[1])
print('curvefit results: ', *result[3])

plt.plot(x_test, lognormal(x_test, *result[1]), linewidth = 0.5, color = 'navy', label = 'MCMC')
plt.plot(x_test, lognormal(x_test, *result[3]), linewidth = 0.5, color = 'orange', label = 'curvefit')
plt.scatter(x_test, y_test, linewidth  = 0.5, s = 1, color = 'darkred')
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.clf()
```

Comment: How do you know theres a mistake in it? what is it supposed to be doing that it doesnt? What does it do instead?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. We don't provide debugging services. The following references give advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. In theory, regarding most examples, the curve fit and the mcmc fit of the data should more or less agree but as you can see when you run the code this is clearly not the case. I did run the same code with a cubic function instead of the lognormal, both for data generation and for fitting of course, and this works fine. Therefore, the error may also be my posterior probability function when using the lognormal function. Thank you once more!